# WebHDFSClient Openfile cannot exceed 2Gb

Tags: c#, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I've encountered a problem with the WebHDFSClient in C#.
I try to access a file **part by part** in the Hadoop File System. It size is 5Gb.

However, the available methods to open a file are :

```
    public Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> OpenFile(string path);
    public Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> OpenFile(string path, int offset, int length);
```

As you can see, the two variables that I need, offset and length are integers. Therefore, it's impossible to retrieve a part beyond the first 2Gb.

Surprisingly, the WebHDFS REST API offers:
(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN)

```
curl -i -L "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=OPEN
                [&offset=<LONG>][&length=<LONG>][&buffersize=<INT>]"
```

Do you see a solution to access file exceeding 2Gb in C# ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like a problem of the C# API, not the webhdfs API. Since this is a webhdfs API, you could directly create http request following the webhdfs specification.

Comment: Yes, that's finally the solution I've been using. Tank you !